# smbclient stopped working, returns NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, debian, netbios, smbclient

*No config changes on the VM or host occurred; results from [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=smbclient%20tree%20connect%20failed%20nt_status_bad_network_name%20netBIOS) and [SE](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=smbclient%20tree%20connect%20failed%20nt_status_bad_network_name) didn't solve issue*

---

I have been using a script to backup some stuff from a Debian VM onto a Windows 7 host (the Debian VM sits on the same Windows 7 host) that worked fine until a couple of days ago, with one of the commands being:

```bash
smbclient //MYWINPC/myShare -U=myusername -c "put $2.sql.gz db/$2.sql.gz"
```

- The script suddenly stopped working yesterday, returning the following error:

  ```bash
  tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
  ```

**Troubleshooting:**

1. Reverted to a VM snapshot of when the script was still working: now it no longer works and produces the error above
2. Since Windows Event Viewer was throwing out the following error, I changed `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to prevent the Debian VM from participating in master browser elections, to no avail

   ```bash
   The master browser has received a server announcement from the computer <my Debian VM> that believes that it is the master browser for the domain on transport NetBT_Tcpip_{<NetBT_Tcpip_ID>. 
   The master browser is stopping or an election is being forced.
   ```
3. Tried accessing the Debian VM from the Windows 7 host via Samba *(successful)*
4. Disabled Windows Firewall: no change
5. `smbclient` log shows `smbclient` is trying to access the share locally rather than on the Windows 7 host:

   ```bash
   [2020/08/17 11:06:46.714698,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3362(process_usershare_file)
   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/myShare failed. Permission denied

   [2020/08/17 11:06:46.715915,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3362(process_usershare_file)
   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/myShare failed. No such file or directory
   ```
6. `smbclient` still works when I replace the `hostname` with its IP address, so somehow the VM is no longer able to resolve the NetBIOS name:

   ```bash
   smbclient //192.168.1.24/myShare -U=myusername -c "put $2.sql.gz db/$2.sql.gz"
   ```
7. From a different Windows PC, I can browse the Windows 7 host and its shares directly by browsing via *Network* in File Manager, so there should be no name resolution issues per se
8. `nbtstat -r` returns the following, so I am not sure why the NetBIOS name for the Windows 7 machine is not included:

   ```bash
   NetBIOS Names Resolution and Registration Statistics
   ----------------------------------------------------

     Resolved By Broadcast     = 4
     Resolved By Name Server   = 0

     Registered By Broadcast   = 18
     Registered By Name Server = 0


   NetBIOS Names Resolved By Broadcast
   ---------------------------------------------
     <ROUTERNAME>
     <DEBIANVM>
     <ROUTERNAME>
     <DEBIANVM>
   ```
9. Running `smbtree -b` produces unexpected results: all shares enumerated point to the Debian VM where Samba is installed, rather than displaying the actual shares for each machine *(shares enumerated are incorrect for all machines except `DEBIANVM`)*:

   ```bash
   WORKGROUP
     \\DEBIANVM              Samba 4.9.5-Debian
       \\DEBIANVM\IPC$         IPC Service (Samba 4.9.5-Debian)
       \\DEBIANVM\homedir
       \\DEBIANVM\webdir
       \\DEBIANVM\print$       Printer Drivers

     \\MYWINPC-2
       \\MYWINPC-2\IPC$        IPC Service (Samba 4.9.5-Debian)
       \\MYWINPC-2\homedir
       \\MYWINPC-2\webdir
       \\MYWINPC-2\print$      Printer Drivers

     \\MYWINPC               MYWINPC
       \\MYWINPC\IPC$          IPC Service (Samba 4.9.5-Debian)
       \\MYWINPC\homedir
       \\MYWINPC\webdir
       \\MYWINPC\print$        Printer Drivers

   ROUTERNAME
     \\ROUTERNAME            Router Gateway
       \\ROUTERNAME\IPC$       IPC Service (Samba 4.9.5-Debian)
       \\ROUTERNAME\homedir
       \\ROUTERNAME\webdir
       \\ROUTERNAME\print$     Printer Drivers
   ```
10. Upgraded VirtualBox to v. 5.2.44 (added for tracking purposes only)

Any idea as to what the problem is?

Comment: See [this](https://serverfault.com/a/137298/343843) answer, but if that doesn't help, google [Samba NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk01Sy_cFCV4MHMey7q4rmt7W-qGoQA%3A1597666644166&source=hp&ei=VHU6X46eB8WWsAXJ1b3ACQ&q=samba+NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME&oq=samba+NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHlAAWABg7CFoAHAAeACAAW-IAW-SAQMwLjGYAQCgAQKqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiOmKuGnKLrAhVFC6wKHclqD5gQ4dUDCAk&uact=5)

Comment: @JW0914 both links largely return the same results I posted above. They either mention security issues such as disabling SELinux - which I do not have - or ensuring Windows Defender is not blocking anything (which it isn't as far as I can see). They do not seem to zero in on the NetBIOS name resolution issue.

Comment: The ServerFault link [first one] is about permissions, however for NETBIOS, three things are usually required for accessing Samba shares on Windows via local hostname only: **(1)** Samba server must have a static IP set via the router; **(2)** Local Domain Name must be the same across the router, server, and client _(on Windows, the local domain name is the Workgroup name)_; **(3)** A hosts file entry on Windows for the Samba server, e.g. `192.168.1.2    freenas    freenas.local` _(format: `<server_ip>` `<server_hostname>` `<server_hostname>.<local_domain_name>`)_

Comment: @JW0914 so, to confirm: **1** the Debian VM onto which Samba is installed does have a static IP; **2** WORKGROUP is being used both in the Win7 machine and in the smb.conf file (not sure what you mean by router though?); **3** are you saying I should add an entry on my Win7 hosts file such as `192.168.1.30    DEBIANVM    DEBIANVM.WORKGROUP`? If so, why was it working up until 2 days ago?

Comment: I'm not sure why, I only know that for NetBIOS issues with Samba, those three things _usually_ must be done _(were you able to browse from another Windows PC using only the local hostname, versus the IP; if so, it's likely not the issue)_. Regarding the router, I had assumed, wrongly I think, the VM and it's client weren't on the same machine _("host" could be interpreted either way, and I took it to mean a Samba reference not the host of the VM)_.

Comment: @JW0914 _were you able to browse from another Windows PC using only the local hostname_ Yes, to confirm, from a different Windows PC I just accessed this Windows 7 machine in question directly by browsing via the _Network_ in File Manager. I did not access it via IP. And yes, both VM and the Windows 7 that hosts it are one and the same. They are the two machines I have been referring to. I tried your suggestion to add the entry in the hosts file, result is the same.